# Override django-taggit tags so that they are always lowercase

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I couldnt find a good answer or solution for multiple tags in a model. the only thing I found close was this:

[How can I limit django-taggit to accept only lowercase words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144498/how-can-i-limit-django-taggit-to-accept-only-lowercase-words)

here is my current code:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase


class TaggedStory(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey("Story")


class TaggedSEO(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey("Story")


class Story(models.Model):
    ...

    tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedStory, blank=True, related_name='story_tags')

    ...

    seo_tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedSEO, blank=True, related_name='seo_tags')
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually implement this at the form level:

```
def clean_tags(self):
    """
    Force all tags to lowercase.
    """
    tags = self.cleaned_data.get('tags', None)
    if tags:
        tags = [t.lower() for t in tags]

    return tags
```

It really depends on how you look at it.  I'm happy with solution because I consider it a validation problem.  If you consider it a data integrity problem, I can understand why you'd want to do it at the model level.  At which point your best bet is to subclass the taggit modules to a point that you can override Tag.save().

Comment: good call, I didn't even think of checking it on the form. I might try this, I just can't wrap my head around subclassing it.

Answer (score 0):

In the appname --> utils file, for eg:(blog --> **init**.py), define a function as follows:

def comma_splitter(tag_string):
"""convert each tag into lowercase"""
return [t.strip().lower() for t in tag_string.split(',') if t.strip()]

And then, in the settings.py file, define and override the default taggit settings as:
TAGGIT_TAGS_FROM_STRING = 'blog.**init**.comma_splitter'